# Correlation coefficient between two arrays of 2D points?

Tags: correlation

I have two arrays of 2D points and I need to estimate their correlation. What formula should I use?

Example of arrays:

$$X: ((1,5),(2,5),(1,7),(4,1)),$$

$$Y: ((3,4),(1,6),(4,6),(4,3)).$$

Comment: A reference is Tobler, W.R. 1965. Computation of the correspondence of geographical patterns. _Papers in Regional Science_ 15: 131–139. doi: 10.1111/j.1435-5597.1965.tb01318.x

Comment: Another reference (much more recent and accessible) http://www.jstatsoft.org/v52/c01/paper

Comment: Brownian correlation? It can be computed between arrays of any, even different dimensionality.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! As for now I started trying Brownian correlation and RV coefficient. The coefficient from Tobler (if I understood correctly) is not symmetrical and it seems like a disadvantage for me, so I didn't try it.

Comment: Why not distance covariance or distance correlation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation#Distance_covariance

Answer (score 2):

The [Pyramid Match Kernel](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~grauman/research/projects/pmk/pmk_projectpage.htm) is a flexible technique for estimating a normalized correspondence strength between multidimensional point sets. It is analogous to $R^2$ in many ways (symmetric, values in $[0,1]$), and could suit your purposes.